# Random Unique Pairs

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of 100 items. I'd like to randomly pair these items with each other. These  pairs must be unique, so there are 4950 possibilities (100 choose 2) total.

Of all 4950 pairs, I'd like to have 1000 pairs randomly selected. But they key is, I'd like each item (of the 100 items) to overall appear the same amount of times (here, 20 times).

I tried to implement this with code a couple of times. And it worked fine when I tried with a lower amount of pairs chosen, but each time I try with the full 1000 pairs, I get stuck in a loop.

Does anyone have an idea for an approach? And what if I change the number of pairs I wish to select (e.g., 1500 rather than 1000 random pairs)?

My attempt (written in VBA):

```
Dim City1(4951) As Integer
Dim City2(4951) As Integer

Dim CityCounter(101) As Integer
Dim PairCounter(4951) As Integer

Dim i As Integer 
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
i = 1

While i < 101
    CityCounter(i) = 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

i = 1
While i < 4951
    PairCounter(i) = 0
    i = i + 1
Wend

i = 1
j = 1

While j < 101

    k = j + 1

    While k < 101
        City1(i) = j
        City2(i) = k

        k = k + 1
        i = i + 1       
    Wend

    j = j + 1

Wend

Dim temp As Integer

i = 1
While i < 1001

    temp = Random(1,4950)

    While ((PairCounter(temp) = 1) Or (CityCounter( (City1(temp)) ) = 20) Or (CityCounter( (City2(temp)) ) = 20))
        temp = Random(1,4950)
    Wend

    PairCounter(temp) = 1
    CityCounter( (City1(temp)) ) = (CityCounter( (City1(temp)) ) + 1)
    CityCounter( (City2(temp)) ) = (CityCounter( (City2(temp)) ) + 1)
    i = i + 1

Wend
```

Comment: That what works for 2 should work for 1000 to.

Comment: Posted my attempt as an edit.

Comment: The random counter seems to be computing one less than the range you want. Should it not be Random(1,4951)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a list, scramble it, and mark every two elements off as a pair.  Add these pairs to a list of pairs.  Ensure that list of pairs is sorted.

Scramble the list of pairs, and add each pair to a "staged" pair list.  Check if it's in the list of pairs.  If it's in the list of pairs, scramble and start over.  If you get the entire list without any duplicates, add the staged pair list to the pair list and start this paragraph over.

Since this involves a nondeterministic step at the end I'm not sure how slow it will be, but it should work.

Comment: This will insure all the items are used the same amount of times. But it fails to insure that there are unique pairs.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks! Efficiency isn't really a concern here.

Answer (score 1):

This is old thread, but I was looking for something similar, and finaly did it myself.

The algorithm is not 100% random (after being a bit "tired" with unsuccessfull random trials starts systematic screening of the table :) - anyway for me - "random enough") but works reasonably fast, and returns required table (unfortunalety not always, but...) usually every second or third use (look in A1 if there is your reqired number of pairs for each item).
Here is VBA code to be run in Excel environment. 
Output is directed to current sheet starting from A1 cell.

```
Option Explicit
Public generalmax%, oldgeneralmax%, generalmin%, alloweddiff%, i&
Public outtable() As Integer
Const maxpair = 100, upperlimit = 20


Sub generate_random_unique_pairs()
'by Kaper 2015.02 for stackoverflow.com/questions/14884975
Dim x%, y%, counter%
Randomize
ReDim outtable(1 To maxpair + 1, 1 To maxpair + 1)
Range("A1").Resize(maxpair + 1, maxpair + 1).ClearContents
alloweddiff = 1
Do
  i = i + 1
  If counter > (0.5 * upperlimit) Then 'try some systematic approach
    For x = 1 To maxpair - 1 ' top-left or:' To 1 Step -1 ' bottom-right
      For y = x + 1 To maxpair
        Call test_and_fill(x, y, counter)
      Next y
    Next x
    If counter > 0 Then
      alloweddiff = alloweddiff + 1
      counter = 0
    End If
  End If
  ' mostly used - random mode
  x = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, maxpair - 1)
  y = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(x + 1, maxpair)
  counter = counter + 1
  Call test_and_fill(x, y, counter)
  If counter = 0 Then alloweddiff = WorksheetFunction.Max(alloweddiff, 1)
  If i > (2.5 * upperlimit) Then Exit Do
Loop Until generalmin = upperlimit
Range("A1").Resize(maxpair + 1, maxpair + 1).Value = outtable
Range("A1").Value = generalmin
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub

Sub test_and_fill(x%, y%, ByRef counter%)
Dim temprowx%, temprowy%, tempcolx%, tempcoly%, tempmax%, j%
tempcolx = outtable(1, x + 1)
tempcoly = outtable(1, y + 1)
temprowx = outtable(x + 1, 1)
temprowy = outtable(y + 1, 1)
tempmax = 1+ WorksheetFunction.Max(tempcolx, tempcoly, temprowx, temprowy)
If tempmax <= (generalmin + alloweddiff) And tempmax <= upperlimit And outtable(y + 1, x + 1) = 0 Then
  counter = 0
  outtable(y + 1, x + 1) = 1
  outtable(x + 1, y + 1) = 1
  outtable(x + 1, 1) = 1 + outtable(x + 1, 1)
  outtable(y + 1, 1) = 1 + outtable(y + 1, 1)
  outtable(1, x + 1) = 1 + outtable(1, x + 1)
  outtable(1, y + 1) = 1 + outtable(1, y + 1)
  generalmax = WorksheetFunction.Max(generalmax, outtable(x + 1, 1), outtable(y + 1, 1), outtable(1, x + 1), outtable(1, y + 1))
  generalmin = outtable(x + 1, 1)
  For j = 1 To maxpair
    If outtable(j + 1, 1) < generalmin Then generalmin = outtable(j + 1, 1)
    If outtable(1, j + 1) < generalmin Then generalmin = outtable(1, j + 1)
  Next j
  If generalmax > oldgeneralmax Then
    oldgeneralmax = generalmax
    Application.StatusBar = "Working on pairs " & generalmax & "Total progress (non-linear): " & Format(1# * generalmax / upperlimit, "0%")
  End If
  alloweddiff = alloweddiff - 1
  i = 0
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an array `appeared[]` which keeps track of how many times each item already appeared in answer. Let's say each element has to appear `k` times. Iterate over the array, and while current element has its `appeared` value less than `k`, choose a random pair for it from that element who also have appeared less than `k` times. Add that pair to answer and increase appearance count for both.

Comment: This looks like what I attempted--see my recent edit. However, when I run the code, I'm getting stuck in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

- create a 2-dimensional 100*100 matrix of booleans, all False
- of these 10K booleans, set 1K of them to true, with the following constraints:
- the diagonal should stay empty
- no row or column should have more than 20 true values
- at the end, every row and column should have 20 True values.

Now, there is the X=Y diagonal symmetry. Just add the following constraints:

- the triangle at one side of the diagonal should stay empty
- in the above constraints, the restrictions for rows&columns should be combined/added